# Inferring RSA algorithm from a publicKeyPem

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, activitypub

According to the [hs2019 algorithm](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/id/draft-richanna-http-message-signatures-00.html#name-hs2019), the actual signing algorithm should be:

> Derived from metadata associated with keyId

My initial thinking was to base it on the number of bits in the signature. I generated some keys to test and by default the size seems to be a differentiator, but the size of the seems unrelated to the signing algorithm.

How can I reliably detect the algorithm used to generate a publiKeyPem?

Edit: I'm specifically trying to determine whether its rsa256 or rsa512

Comment: You should clarify your question to state it's related to ActivityPub, rather than only having a single tag for it.

Comment: I'm pretty the "derived from metadata" statement means that the keyID, e.g. `myKey99`, uniquely identifies a key on your system where there is also metadata that tells what kind of key it is. The metadata is carried along with key, and the key is uniquely identified by the keyID, but the key itself is not in the protocol, at least at that spot.

Comment: the @PresidentJamesK.Polk the keyID resolves to a publicKeyPem see: https://json.blinry.org/#https://mediaformat.org/author/dev